# Entity Framework and Union Statement

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 'QueueA', COUNT(*) FROM QueueA_Table
UNION
SELECT 'QueueB', COUNT(*) FROM QueueB_Table
```

How do I do the equivalent with the Entity Framework?  The best I could do was:

```
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    return new QueueCount[] {
      new QueueCount("QueueA", db.QueueA_Table.Count()),
      new QueueCount("QueueB", db.QueueB_Table.Count())
    };  
}
```

However, this results in two separate Queries to the database according to LINQPad.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [QueueA_Table] AS [t0]
GO
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [QueueB_Table] AS [t0]
```

Is there a way to write it so that only one query is sent to the database?

Comment: You could try a future query. https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the prettiest or most maintainable way to do it:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueueA_Table
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueueB_Table");
```

or if you want to populate a class:

```
public class QueueCount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<QueueCount>(@"
    SELECT [Name] = 'QueueA', [Count] = COUNT(*) FROM QueueA_Table
    UNION
    SELECT [Name] = 'QueueB', [Count] = COUNT(*) FROM QueueB_Table");
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the code does not give me the queue name.  If I try something like: 'return db.Database.SqlQuery<QueueCount>(sql).ToList();' is that the QueueCount has parameters in its constructor and it returns only 2 records that are default values.  I'd hate to implement the code above and then have to iterate trying to match the queue to the row number.

Comment: @BillN: oh you could get `SqlQuery` to populate a class if you have a default constructor and properties. See the edit.

Comment: As you say 'not the prettiest' but better than making x number of calls to Db instead of one.  Thanks @jjj

Answer (score 0):

The query is ugly, and it's pretty much a hack:

```
(from s in QueueA_Table.Take(1)
 select new List<int> {
    QueueA_Table.Count(),
    QueueB_Table.Count()
 }).First()
```

or

```
(from s in QueueA_Table.Take(1)
 select new  {
     QueueA = QueueA_Table.Count(),
     QueueB = QueueB_Table.Count()
 })
```